How to extend Express Request Object with TypeScript
I am trying to add a property to the Request object of express
First create a middleware to validate the session and the token brings the companyId
import { verifyToken } from '../utils/jwt/jwt';

declare module 'express-serve-static-core' {
  interface Request {
    companyId: string;
  }
}

export const validateSession = (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
): void => {
  try {
    const jwtByUser = req.headers.authorization ?? null;
    const jwt = jwtByUser?.split(' ').pop();
    console.log(jwtByUser);
    console.log(jwt);

    const session = verifyToken(`${jwt}`);

    if (!session) {
      res.status(400).send('Invalid Token Session');
    }
    // Add userId and companyId to the request object
    // req.user.id = session.user.id;
    req.companyId = session.companyId;
    // req.user.role = session.user.role;
    // req.user.email = session.user.email;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send('Invalid Session');
  }
};

Note: I have to put the same thing that I put on the index.d.ts if not I have an error req.companyId doesn't exist
Then create a file inside src/types index.d.ts
import 'express-serve-static-core';

declare module 'express-serve-static-core' {
  export interface Request {
    companyId: string;
  }
}

then inside my user.routes.ts file I add the middleware and finally in my controller I should be able to use this property.
this is my route
router.get('/', validateSession, usersController.getAllUsers);
this is my controller user.controller:
getAllUsers = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> => {
    const companyId = req.companyId;
    console.log(companyId);
    const filteredUser = await this.usersService.getAllUsers();

    handleResult(res, filteredUser, 200);
  };

I have seen several posts where they ask to modify the tsconfig.json file I have tried thousands of things but none of them work for me I keep getting the same error.
The error occurs when I start the server with npm run dev.
this is the error:
Error importing module: Error: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript: src/app/users/infrastructure/controller/user.controller.ts(60,27): error TS2339: Property 'companyId' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
this is my folder structure:
x

What's your import for those Request/Reponse types look like? What if you remove those annotations?

I could solve it.
I am using ts-node so I'd to add the flag --files to npm run dev script.
I expend 7 hours or so just to discover that.

Wow that saved me a lot of pain.

I have verified that:

Your solution works fine if you copy

declare module 'express-serve-static-core' {
  export interface Request {
    companyId: string;
  }
}

into the file where you are using it (eg. your controller)

Or: adding an index.d.ts file like:


export * from'express-serve-static-core' 

declare module 'express-serve-static-core' {
    interface Request {
      companyId: string;
    }
  }

Also appears to work.

I tried option 2 but it didn't work I added the file index.d.ts but I have to modify the tsconfig.json?

Have you done the export thing?

I could solve it finally, the problem was with ts-node and I have to add --files flag to npm run dev script.
